# need to check if files are there?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk, ksh

Inside one folder i have some files

```
UEDP01_20120821.csv
UEDP02_20120821.csv
UEDP03_20120821.csv
UEDP04_20120821.csv
UEDP05_20120821.csv
```

Just want to check all the files are present. If any one file is missing need to create one empty file with same name.

Eg:

```
UEDP01_20120821.csv
UEDP02_20120821.csv
UEDP04_20120821.csv
UEDP05_20120821.csv
```

**UEDP03_20120821.csv** if this file is missing, then need to create the same file.

Comment: Thanks alot guys for your reply. let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Check if a regular file of the name exists. If it does not, create it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw(
    UEDP01_20120821.csv
    UEDP02_20120821.csv
    UEDP03_20120821.csv
    UEDP04_20120821.csv
    UEDP05_20120821.csv
);

for my $file (@files) {
    next if -f $file;
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If `file.txt` is your list of files, in bash:

```
while read fname; do
    [[ -f $fname ]] || touch "$fname"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the only non-POSIX feature here is the `[[...]]`, and I only used that to avoid the need to quote `$fname`. Change to `[ -f "$fname" ]` for full(?) POSIX compliance.

Comment: I _believe_ `read` has inconsistent behaviour across POSIX-compliant implementations. I've no good source for that, and don't have the energy/impetus to look it up right now, but I know I've been told to avoid `read` when writing portable shell scripts.

Comment: The spec only defines a single option (`-r`) for `read`, so if you avoid other options, perhaps `read` is safe.

Answer (score 4):

why do you need a script for this?

as dennis suggested you can use -a for just changing the access time of the existing files.

```
  touch -a UEDP0{1..5}_20120821.csv
```

will directly create the missing files.

Comment: The downside of not testing for the presence of an existing file (as Anon ymous did) is that you unconditionally update the `mtime` of each file.  You might want to preserve that information for existing files.

Comment: Yes ...but the OP's did not ask that he wants to preserve the mtime of existing files!

Comment: It's a stretch to assume he does not.

Comment: Use `touch -a` and it will only change the access time, but will still create the missing files. The `-a` option is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html).

Answer (score 2):

Shell Script:-

```
for i in {1..5}
do
file="UEDP0${i}_20120821.csv"
if [ -f $file ]
then
    echo the file exists
else
 >$file
fi
done
```

Comment: shell is not perl, don't use a `$` on the left-hand side of an assignment. Also, I'd do the quoting a little differently: `file="UEDP0${i}_20120821.csv"`

Answer (score 1):

If your list of files change dynamically then you can have a list of files in  another file, which would make it easier:

If you have your files in a file called `list` then:

`list` will have the content:

```
  UEDP01_20120821.csv
  UEDP02_20120821.csv
  UEDP03_20120821.csv
  UEDP04_20120821.csv
  UEDP05_20120821.csv
```

---

```
awk 'system("touch "$1"");' list
```

would create the files if they don't exist.

Comment: This is a waste of a process -- `cat`.  Simply do: `awk '{system("touch "$1"")}' list

Comment: @JRFerguson you're right. I was thinking different things posted as such!

Comment: using awk just doesn't smell like the right tool, particularly as you're just calling out the shell anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just opening a file for output will create it for you.

You don't say where your list of file names comes from, but in the program below I have hard-coded it.

Note that there is no need to close the file handle `$fh` as it is closed automatically by Perl when the variable goes out of scope at the end of each cycle of the loop.

The [`-e` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) will check whether a file exists. Alternatively you could use `-f` which is true if the node exists *and isn't a directory*. If there is already a directory by the same name then the `open` will fail

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw/
  UEDP01_20120821.csv
  UEDP02_20120821.csv
  UEDP03_20120821.csv
  UEDP04_20120821.csv
  UEDP05_20120821.csv
/;

for my $file (@files) {
  open my $fh, '>', $file or die $! unless -e $file;
}
```

---

**Update**

As suggested by Bill Ruppert, you may prefer to open the files for append, regardless of whether they exist. This will create the files if necessary but leave them intact if they are already there

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw/
  UEDP01_20120821.csv
  UEDP02_20120821.csv
  UEDP03_20120821.csv
  UEDP04_20120821.csv
  UEDP05_20120821.csv
/;

open my $fh, '>>', $_ or die $! for @files;
```

Comment: Will this overwrite the existing files when $fh goes out of scope at the end of the for loop?  Perhaps us `>>` instead?

Comment: The `unless` modifier prevents existing files from ever being opened.

Comment: @Bill Ruppert: The code is fine as it stands, but actually I think I prefer your way. An open to append will leave an existing file intact and create an empty file if it doesn't exist